# `npm install` runs when project is opened in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, npm-install

In Visual Studio 2015, every time I open my solution `npm install` is running and installing all the packages. I don't want to run this automatically every time but only run via command line.

How do I stop it from running?

```
{
  "name": "ebr",
  "author": "vj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.3.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.0",
    "ng2-pagination": "^0.4.1",
    "pdfmake": "0.1.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.14.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.12",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-tfs-checkout": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.1.5",
    "gulp-tslint": "^6.0.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.9",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.31",
    "tslint": "^3.14.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your `package.json`, I'd bet it has something to do with event bindings in VS.  VS has it's own events such as `Project Open`

Comment: @DaveV I included package.json please take a look at it

Comment: This issue with automatically running npm install has been fixed in Visual studio update 5 patch, I installed it today and its not running any background tasks unless running it.